# DeltaManipulation in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have found this [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a2b8234a-f713-40ce-a896-fc8b82ccc817/pinch-to-zoom-feature-implementation-in-in-c?forum=winappswithcsharp) which seams to be exactly what I need. But it does not work in an universal app.

Xaml:

```
<Rectangle Name="TestRectangle"
Width="200"
Height="200"
Fill="Blue" 
ManipulationMode="All" />
```

C#:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add handler for the ManipulationDelta event
    TestRectangle.ManipulationDelta += new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
        CompositeTransform transform = element.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
        if (transform != null)
        {
            transform.ScaleX *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale;
            transform.ScaleY *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale;
            transform.Rotation += e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation * 180 / Math.PI;
            transform.TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
            transform.TranslateY += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        }
    });

    TestRectangle.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
}
```

Here is the error:

> 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'DeltaManipulation' and no extension method 'DeltaManipulation' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, `Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs` has [`Delta`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationdeltaroutedeventargs.delta) property instead of `DeltaManipulation`. So try to replace `DeltaManipulation` with `Delta` :

```
if (transform != null)
{
    transform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: Yes this is it! It works on devices with touch screens. Do you know how to use the zoom by mouse? Control+MouseWheel does not work.